# Finding neigborhood in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I need to know how I can find nodes with coordinate (x,y), around x0, with r < r0, which r is sqrt(x^2+y^2). In fact I wrote it but as my number of nodes is 10000, in takes a while to reach the answer. I'm looking for a MATLAB command for it.

Answer (score 1):

I would try constructing a Delaunay triangulation for the nodes assembly. Then it is easier (and more efficient) to find neighbors.

please have a look at "DelaunayTri" class
http://www.mathworks.ch/help/techdoc/ref/delaunaytriclass.html

and "DelaunayTri" itself to see if it suits your needs.
http://www.mathworks.ch/help/techdoc/ref/delaunaytri.html